# Internet Explorer CSS mirroring content?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browserstack

I'm having an issue with css in Internet Explorer, however it is only showing when i'm testing in Browserstack. It shows on all versions of IE that I test on with Windows 7. On my PC it appears fine with my version of IE and when I change the browser mode from within. I'm not sure if it's a quirk or Browserstack or an IE issue that i'm missing.

The area concerned has 2 paragraph tags, 1 floated left the other right, both width 45%, display block, overflow hidden. Each has an anchor tag inside display block, with a background color and border on. The second link is like it's mirroring itself, looks really odd and i can't find anything on this, anyone seen this before and know how to fix? Or is it a Browserstack quirk?

[Screenshot of what's happening here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkD8U.png)

Thanks!

edit, added code:

```
        <style>
        a.button {
            background: #c10075;
            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
            color: white;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 15px 0;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 2px solid #c10075;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #8e0056;
            border-right: 2px solid #8e0056;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Rokkitt, serif, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 28px;
            display: block;
        }
        a.button:hover {
            background: #8e0056;
            border: 2px solid #8e0056;
            color: white;
        }
        .cta-buttons p{
            width: 45%;
            float: left;
        }
        .cta-buttons p.last{
            float: right;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="container cta-buttons">
         <p>
               <a href="" class="button">Apply now</a>
         </p>
         <p class="last">
               <a href="" class="button">Book your visit</a>
        </p>
    </div><!-- .cta-buttons -->
```

Comment: It would make it much more easy to help you if you added your code.

Comment: @pb1uk I'm Umang from BrowserStack. Could you please share more details on the email we've sent? We would be glad to help.

Comment: @Umang sure, where has the email been sent?